# NHibernate query interception

Tags: sql, nhibernate

Is there any way to get the query text - i.e. plain SQL - of an NHibernate query from a DetachedCriteria object (or any NHibernate object, I just want to be pointed in the right direction) BEFORE it is sent to my server? If so, can I prevent it from executing?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.. why do you need this? tell us what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: I want to return the result of a detachedCriteria.GetExecutableCriteria()
to a DataTable. I need to be able to sort the results returned, and to be able to sort, I need to know the types of each object. Determining types dynamically is an n^2 operation (the GetExecutableCriteria() returns object[][]), and having the SQL text would eliminate this problem.

Comment: if you want to sort, why not just use AddOrder()?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is an easy way of doing this. There might be a listener you can use to display the sql and then abort the execution. I've never used one for this purpose.

If you simply want to debug your queries and don't want to hit your database then write some tests using an [in-memory database](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/28/nhibernate-unit-testing.aspx). In my opinion this is a much better strategy.

You can observe the queries that are being generated by tailing your log files or using [NHProf](http://nhprof.com/).